# How to use bootstrap-4 blade templates in lumen?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, lumen

In a lumen 5.5 application I want to use the provided boostrap-4 blade template from `vendor/illuminate/pagination/resources/views/bootstrap-4.blade.php`.

So I changed

```
{{ $pics->links() }}
```

to

```
{{ $pics->links('pagination.bootstrap-4') }}
```

Unfortunately I do only get an error message.

How can I make use of the provided bootstrap-4 template?

Error message:

```
(2/2) ErrorException
View [bootstrap-4] not found. (View: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ernst/Source/php/pics/resources/views/admin.blade.php)
in FileViewFinder.php (line 137)
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(InvalidArgumentException), 0)
in PhpEngine.php (line 45)
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ernst/Source/php/pics/storage/framework/views/4c88ecb1e4d59a7ef025e62d1c88dd590ab7939b.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'pics' => object(LengthAwarePaginator)))
in CompilerEngine.php (line 59)
at CompilerEngine->get('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ernst/Source/php/pics/resources/views/admin.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'pics' => object(LengthAwarePaginator)))
in View.php (line 137)
at View->getContents()
in View.php (line 120)
at View->renderContents()
in View.php (line 85)
at View->render()
in Response.php (line 42)
at Response->setContent(object(View))
in Response.php (line 201)
at Response->__construct(object(View))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 431)
at Application->prepareResponse(object(View))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 373)
at Application->callControllerCallable(array(object(AdminController), 'admin'), array())
in RoutesRequests.php (line 339)
at Application->callLumenController(object(AdminController), 'admin', array(true, array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminController@admin'), array()))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 313)
at Application->callControllerAction(array(true, array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminController@admin'), array()))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 275)
at Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(array(true, array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminController@admin'), array()))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 260)
at Application->handleFoundRoute(array(true, array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminController@admin'), array()))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 160)
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}()
in RoutesRequests.php (line 413)
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 166)
at Application->dispatch(null)
in RoutesRequests.php (line 107)
at Application->run()
in index.php (line 28)
(1/2) InvalidArgumentException
View [bootstrap-4] not found.
in FileViewFinder.php (line 137)
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('bootstrap-4', array('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ernst/Source/php/pics/resources/views'))
in FileViewFinder.php (line 79)
at FileViewFinder->find('bootstrap-4')
in Factory.php (line 128)
at Factory->make('bootstrap-4', array('paginator' => object(LengthAwarePaginator), 'elements' => array(array('http://local.pics/public/admin?page=1', 'http://local.pics/public/admin?page=2', 'http://local.pics/public/admin?page=3', 'http://local.pics/public/admin?page=4', 'http://local.pics/public/admin?page=5', 'http://local.pics/public/admin?page=6', 'http://local.pics/public/admin?page=7', 'http://local.pics/public/admin?page=8'), '...', array('http://local.pics/public/admin?page=36', 'http://local.pics/public/admin?page=37'))))
in LengthAwarePaginator.php (line 92)
at LengthAwarePaginator->render('bootstrap-4', array())
in LengthAwarePaginator.php (line 78)
at LengthAwarePaginator->links('bootstrap-4')
in 4c88ecb1e4d59a7ef025e62d1c88dd590ab7939b.php (line 63)
at include('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ernst/Source/php/pics/storage/framework/views/4c88ecb1e4d59a7ef025e62d1c88dd590ab7939b.php')
in PhpEngine.php (line 43)
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ernst/Source/php/pics/storage/framework/views/4c88ecb1e4d59a7ef025e62d1c88dd590ab7939b.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'pics' => object(LengthAwarePaginator)))
in CompilerEngine.php (line 59)
at CompilerEngine->get('/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ernst/Source/php/pics/resources/views/admin.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'pics' => object(LengthAwarePaginator)))
in View.php (line 137)
at View->getContents()
in View.php (line 120)
at View->renderContents()
in View.php (line 85)
at View->render()
in Response.php (line 42)
at Response->setContent(object(View))
in Response.php (line 201)
at Response->__construct(object(View))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 431)
at Application->prepareResponse(object(View))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 373)
at Application->callControllerCallable(array(object(AdminController), 'admin'), array())
in RoutesRequests.php (line 339)
at Application->callLumenController(object(AdminController), 'admin', array(true, array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminController@admin'), array()))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 313)
at Application->callControllerAction(array(true, array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminController@admin'), array()))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 275)
at Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(array(true, array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminController@admin'), array()))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 260)
at Application->handleFoundRoute(array(true, array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminController@admin'), array()))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 160)
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}()
in RoutesRequests.php (line 413)
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure))
in RoutesRequests.php (line 166)
at Application->dispatch(null)
in RoutesRequests.php (line 107)
at Application->run()
in index.php (line 28)
```

Comment: Not sure if it'll be relevant, but can you show the error message please?

Comment: I think you need to run a `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination` or something like that

Comment: artisan for lumen is much less powerful than in laravel. There are no vendor commands.

Comment: Here is the vendor publish command package for lumen https://github.com/laravelista/lumen-vendor-publish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never using Lumen even once. But, here's what I got from Laravel.

By using php scope resolution operator `::`, Laravel tries to find blade template in

```
root/resources/views/vendor/{target_dir}
```

Or, any packages that used to publish blade templates. So, either way to call it should work

```
$pics->links('pagination::bootstrap-4')
$pics->links('vendor.pagination.bootstrap-4')
```

The latter encourages you to publish vendor package, actually.

Comment: The `::` operator works. The second version doesn't.